# Babel do not convert to ES5 if NodeJS is supported

Tags: node.js, babeljs

English is not my native language, please excuse typing errors.

NodeJS LTS now 4.x and 6.x, which is part of the ES6 syntax is only supported in 6.x, [node.green](http://node.green/).

I have a back-end Node project needs to support the Node 4.x version now, but I have to used some syntax only worked in 6.x version. So I introduced Babel with `preset-es2015`. But with this preset, Babel transform from ES6 to ES5.

ES6 part of the syntax, such as `const`, `let` the performance is higher than var (This is a hypothesis, the actual situation certainly not so simple).

My code is running on ES6 support at 99% of Node 6.x or 57% of Node 4.x, there is really not need to downgrade all code to ES5.

So I would like to know how to let Babel don't convert ES6 syntax to ES5 if NodeJS is supported.

Further, does Babel support detecting code support for the current operating environment and intelligently converting it?

Thank you.

UPDATE: [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`babel-preset-env`**](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) lets you target a specific Node (or browser) version. I.e. features that are supported by that version are not transpiled. Example:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": 4
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

> Further, does Babel support detecting code support for the current operating environment and intelligently converting it?

Transpilation is usually offline, *before* the code is executed in the target environment, so that's not really possible.

Comment: Thank you for answer. [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env‌​) is what I want. I have test, and it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile ES6 to ES5 you need to install Babel ES2015 preset.

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Then you need to enable this preset. One way to enable this ES6 to ES5 compilation is using babel-loader query string:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'
      }
    ]
  }
```

or query option:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I have use `preset-es2015` and don't want to Babel convert all code to ES5.

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using webpack? You should at least mention that your example is for webpack.